# C#: Toggle comments between two a section of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Consider the code below, when I have both these lines selected, is there a way to toggle the comments between the lines? For example invoking a shortcut or a feature that would uncomment quick brown fox and comment foo bar. Invoke again and it would comment quick brown fox and uncomment foo bar.

```
//quick brown fox
foo bar
```

Comment: Not out of the box. But you can [write your own extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022) to do it.

Comment: It does not provide such functionality, it needs to create a extension for it.

Answer (score 0):

Toggling comments works similar for the hole selection. I think it's not possible. See keyboard shortcuts: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

`Edit.ToggleLineComment` (Ctrl+K,/) or for german IDE (Strg+K,Strg+§)
`ReSharper.ReSharper_LineComment` (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-C) or (Strg+Alt+7)